# How can Serilog send a custom "_id" field to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, serilog

We're using Serilog and have recently installed the Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch sink to be able to log entries to our company's Elasticsearch server.

We want to be able to call Elasticsearch with a custom "_id" field so that we can update existing entries with additional information as our distributed transactions travel through a Saga pattern of events.

Using a custom _id field with Elasticsearch is very easy to do in JavaScript, but the Serilog Elasticsearch Sink doesn't seem to support this.  The _id field is assembled deep in an "ElasticsearchPayloadReader", without any options to override it.

```
        protected override void AddToPayLoad(string nextLine)
        {
            var indexName = _getIndexForEvent(nextLine, _date);
            var action = default(object);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_pipelineName))
            {
                action = new { index = new { _index = indexName, _type = _typeName, _id = _count + "_" + Guid.NewGuid() } };
            }
            else
            {
                action = new { index = new { _index = indexName, _type = _typeName, _id = _count + "_" + Guid.NewGuid(), pipeline = _pipelineName } };
            }

            var actionJson = _serialize(action);
            _payload.Add(actionJson);
            _payload.Add(nextLine);
            _count++;
        }
```

Are we overlooking something?  Is there a supported way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The current Serilog sink for elastic search does not support this.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch/issues/287

A valid work around and more standard convention is to is to pass in a Saga Id along as another field other than the _id field.